# Rails flexible routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project in which the core entity is "building". Every building belongs to a category, subcategory and city. What I'm just trying to do is to have flexible URLs like this:

```
/nice-building-name (f.e.: "/eiffel-tower")
/category (f.e.: "/big")
/category/subcategory (f.e.: "/big/red")
/category/subcategory/city (f.e.: "/big/red/prague")
/subcategory (f.e.: "/red")
/subcategory/city (f.e.: "/red/prague")
/city (f.e.: "/prague")
```

The problem is that if I specify routes like this:

```
match ':category_id/buildings',  to: 'buildings#category',  via: 'get'
match ':subcategory_id/buildings',  to: 'buildings#subcategory',  via: 'get'
```

It always matches only the first specified route and in no case can I reach the second. What I need is a behaviour like this:

I enter URL like: /7/places. It checks whether there is a category with ID 7. If no, it doesn't stop but it checkes whether there is a subcategory with ID 7. If yes, it matches the second route.

I think the point is clear now. Is it possible to have URL like this? Is it possible to achieve this "dynamic" routing? Or at least something similar?

Thanks forward.

Comment: Are you saying that ... /category/subcategory would go to a SubcategoriesController and /city would go to a CitiesController and so on? Where the category, subcategory, city, etc would be some kind of primary key for an associated object? Is /buildings/:building_name not acceptable? And /categories/:category_name and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible, take a look at this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

From the above link:

3.2 Dynamic Segments
You can set up as many dynamic segments within a regular route as you like. Anything other than :controller or :action will be available to the action as part of params. If you set up this route:

```
get ':controller/:action/:id/:user_id'
```

An incoming path of /photos/show/1/2 will be dispatched to the show action of the PhotosController. params[:id] will be "1", and params[:user_id] will be "2".

So for your first example you could set up a route such as
get ':controller/:action/:building_name'

then incoming requests to path `/buildings/show/my_building_name`

would be routed to the building controller's show action, and a params[:building_name] would  be available set to "my_building_name"

Comment: it's really not constructive to down-vote and not leave a comment as to why.  Blastfurnace left a valid comment, stating that I should not post link-only answers, which I corrected.  If there is something else unhelpful with this answer, it would be nice to know what it is, so I can avoid the mistake in the future.

Comment: I've updated my first post. Can you look at it, please?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your association (belongs_to, has_many, has_one...) are set properly, you can develop you routes for each resource.

```
#routes.rb
resources: buildings

resources: categories do
  resources: subcategories do
      resources: cities
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, my associations are set properly, but case you gave, my routes looks like: /category/:category_id/buildings and not like /:category_id/buildings. Please, see my first post, I've just updated it.